# Convert Win10 LTSC custom image to iso or wim

Tags: windows-10, window, wds, windows-iot-core

i have about thousand  dell wyse 5070 thin clients that i manage from WMS ( wyse manager suit)
the administration guide mentions only one way to re-image the devices using usb flash tool that burns custom image named WIE10_LTSC_2019_UNIFIED that can be downloaded from dell support website
https://www.dell.com/support/home/en-us/product-support/servicetag/0-Y0lGeVlaSWtnLytyNVRkdzIrSHppUT090/drivers

i have prepsys , capture and deploy wim through WDS but this way causing serious problem with wyse manager , deployed devices can not be managed from wyse

is there any way to edit the original image to use it with WDS ?
thanks in advance
[the original image files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2IsQi.png)